# VIM open YAML with syntax highlighting from STDIN

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

How would you specify a syntax type when piping content into `vim -R`?

Since vim has a vim.yalm plugin, this hi-lights the contents of the file properly

```
vim -R foo.yaml
```

However, does not detect the syntax when using pipes

```
cat foo.yaml | vim -R -
```

A work around is to type`:set syntax=yaml` once the file is open.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
cat foo.yaml | vim -R - --syntax=yaml
```

Is there a way to pipe the contents of a file to `vim -R` with syntax hi-lighting?

**Reasoning**

I want to be able to preview kubernetes config files before I apply them to the cluster. I want the previews to have color.

```
helm template foo | vim -R -
```

or

```
sops --decrypt foo.yaml | vim -R -
sops --decrypt foo.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: After asking this question, I discovered possible duplicate on a different site https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268889/vim-force-specific-syntax-via-command-line-argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way:

```
cat foo.yml | vim -c "doautocmd BufRead x.yml" -R -
```

This tells Vim, that it should execute the `autocmd`'s as if a file named `x.yml` was loaded. This includes file type detection and hence syntax. The name `x.yml` is only used to identify the commands to run, it is not used for anything else.

Also possible:

```
cat foo.yml | vim -c "doautocmd Filetype yaml" -R -
```

This tells Vim to execute the `autocmd`'s that are run when the filetype `yaml` is detected.

Answer (score 4):

As shown on a different stack overflow site, it is possible to [pass options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268889/vim-force-specific-syntax-via-command-line-argument_) to vim using `-c`

e.g `vim -R -c 'set syntax=yaml' -`

Wrapping this in a bash function gives me what I'm looking for

```
function vaml() {
  vim -R -c 'set syntax=yaml' -;
}
```

So now I can do

```
cat foo.yaml | vaml
```

Comment: `:set syntax` only covers the syntax highlighting; better use `setfiletype yaml` so that you also get any buffer-local options, indenters, mappings, and other customizations that may be defined for YAML files.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the autocmd answer from above: add the following to your `.vimrc` or `.vim/ftdetect/k8s-yaml.vim`:

```
" file detection of kubernetes yamls
function! DetectYaml()
   if getline(1) =~ 'apiVersion:'
     setfiletype yaml
   endif
   if getline(1) =~ '---'
     setfiletype yaml
   endif
endfunction

augroup filetypedetect
  au StdinReadPost * call DetectYaml()
augroup END
```

This way you can just pipe the output into `vim -`. The detection is tailored to Kuberntes & helm Yaml-Files which start either with `---` (helm) or `apiVersion:` (kubectl)